# cURL Output in Ruby

Tags: ruby, curl

I am trying to store the output that cURL returns when uploading a file. Here is my code:

```
$file = '/Users/newmedia/Desktop/test.mov'
$credentials = '-u username:password ftp://upload.website.com'

$upload = `/usr/bin/curl -T #{$file} #{$credentials}`

# Return cURL response
puts $upload
```

If the transfer is successful it returns nothing (which is fine), but if it fails it should return something like: `curl: (67) Access denied: 530` (like it does in the terminal).

I know that I can use `$?` to return a number that I can use to confirm success or failure, but I would like to store the actual message in a log.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Found this blog post on capturing STDERR with ruby backticks: http://www.weheartcode.com/2007/09/14/capturing-stderr-with-ruby-backticks/

`out = 'ourlinuxcmd 2>&1'` (replace ' with backticks)....

the 2>&1 bit tells the shell to redirect stderr to stdout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, variables prefixed with `$` are global variables in Ruby, which may or may not be what you want (hint: generally it's the latter).

Now for your actual problem: `curl`'s error message gets written to `stderr`, but the backticks only return what's written to `stdout`.

Take a look at the following blog post:

http://tech.natemurray.com/2007/03/ruby-shell-commands.html

What you need is either [IO#popen](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/IO.html#method-c-popen) or [Open3#popen3](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3).

Comment: Great resource. Thanks! I couldn't use Open3#popen3 because it doesn't wait for a return status.